# Why is an instance variable used instead of a local variable in a module?

Tags: ruby, memoization

I saw this code for a Ruby on Rails application:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by id: session[:user_id]
  end

  ...
end
```

Why is an instance variable used instead of a local variable in `current_user` method? When I change it to a local variable, everything is the same as using an instance variable.

I read that an instance variable can be used in many other classes that include this module. But in this case, they are defined in `current_user` method for storing the user's value `@current_user`. How is this used in many other classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This roughly means that if `@current_user`, as an instance variable of global request/response scope (Controller/View/Helpers), has already been defined, use it as `current_user`. Otherwise, assign it the user that corresponds to the id stored in the session do what you do.

In other words, this is similar to:

```
def current_user
    if @current_user # this will be false in every hit, for the same request
        @current_user
    else
        User.find_by id: session[:user_id]
    end
end
```

And this should be enough.

But then, you may use again `current_user` in some other part of the code, let's say in the controller, for the same request.

This means, that `current_user` will have to hit the DB again (caching aside). And you would like to avoid that, if you can. So, why not store the user in a global instance variable?

Thus:

```
def current_user
    if @current_user # this will be false for the first hit, true for every subsequent request
        @current_user 
    else
        @current_user = User.find_by id: session[:user_id]
    end
end
```

And since we do this, why not use the shorthand method for it?

So, finally:

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by id: session[:user_id]
end
```

The answer is, you do this for reusability shake, within the same request/response.

Answer (score 2):

> @current_user ||= User.find_by id: session[:user_id]

This is using some Ruby shortcuts here, so let's expand to be this instead:

```
 if @current_user == nil
   @current_user = User.find_by id: session[:user_id]
 end

 return @current_user
```

Ok, great. But this database lookup could actually take a long time (say tens of milliseconds per each time we call it.). Which might not feel like a long time, but it will eventually add up - Rails apps call the current user a lot (only requesting once vs dozens of times also reduces load on your database server). (Absent of any kind of caching ActiveRecord and Rails is doing behind your back that is...

So we save the results into an instance variable we have for later.

So if you did something like this instead, in your current_user method

```
if my_current_user
  my_current_user = User.find_by id: session[:user_id]
end

return my_current_user
```

This will always go into that `if` statement, always do the lookup, put the answer in a local and return it. Next time it has no knowledge it's already looked it up, so will do the same database query again, getting the result, etc etc. So it may work, but it'll be slower than using an instance variable here.

There is a disadvantage, of course. Modules in Ruby can be imported into classes - the methods in the module become methods of the class. So yes, now you have created an instance variable for all the classes that import your module. This is... probably not entirely kind (what if some other module also uses that name??), but ehhhhhhhhhhh.... in a small beginner codebase it won't matter.